# Ajax response 0 when using processData and contentType. Input='file[]'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**html:**

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```

**js:**

```
alert( filesArray );
3 three images.// 
// [object File],[object File],[object File]

// new FormData object.
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append( 'files[]', filesArray );

jQuery.ajax
({
    url: ajaxurl, // uploadfile.php
    type: "POST",
    data:   {
                action: 'auto_post',
                form_data: formData
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function( data )
    {
       alert( data );
    },
    error: function( data )
    { }
});
```

When i don't use:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

I got: (error)

```
TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.
```

What to do now? I need the the formData to send to the php server side using ajax.

**uploadfile.php**

I need to access like this here:

```
$_FILES["files"]["name"];
```

**Ajax data get here:**

```
// Ajax Funtion.
function aap_auto_post()
{
    echo $_FILES['files']['name'];
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_auto_post', 'aap_auto_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_auto_post', 'aap_auto_post' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values sent in an ajax request must be appended to the FormData object, not just the files. Also the files have to be added individually.

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++){
    formData.append( 'files[]', filesArray[i]);
}
formData.append( 'action', 'auto_post');
...
data: formData,
```

Comment: what's this: `formData.append( 'action', 'auto_post');`

Comment: That's  the action parameter you're trying to post

Comment: getting the same thing: `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`

Comment: its in `jquery.1.11.js` file:  

`...,d=[],e=function(a,b){b=m.isFunction(b)?b():null==b?"":b,d[d.length]=encodeURICo...`

Comment: Does the console have a stack trace? You can use that to find the line in your own code.

Comment: i am using firefox. i don't know about the stack trace thing. I saw this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390598/append-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-formdata) which said use `processData: false,
contentType: false,` but then i get 0 response from the ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69034/discussion-between-musa-and-hassan-ali).

Answer (score 0):

Use the id to select the form like this

```
$('form#YOUR_FORM_ID').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();   
 var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
 $.ajax({
   url: 'YOUR_SERVER_URI',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   async: true,         
   success: function (data) { 
         alert(data);
   },
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
   });  
      return false;

});
```

This will process the $_FILES as well on the server side. Do it as you do it normally.