# TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData with processData and contentType false both

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

first all, scuse me my english. I'm trying to submit a form with ajax, my js code is the next:

```
$("#formPublicidad").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataForm = new FormData(document.getElementById('formPublicidad'));

    if(dataForm.get('url') == '' || dataForm.get('texto') == '' || dataForm.get('imagen') == '') {
        $("#formMsg").text('Debe rellenar todos los campos');
        $("#formMsg").css('display', 'block');
    }else {
        $("#formMsg").text('Cargando...');
        $(".btn-form-pub").attr('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'publicidad.ajax.php', 
            method: 'POST',
            data: dataForm,
            pocessData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                var msg = JSON.stringify(response.msg).replace(/\"/g, "");
                $(".btn-form-pub").attr('disabled', false);
                if(msg != 'success') {
                    document.getElementById('formMsg').textContent = msg;
                    document.getElementById('formMsg').style = 'display: block;';
                }else {
                    $("#formModal").modal('hide');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" id="formPublicidad">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <span id="formMsg"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="posicion" id="pubPos">
        <label for="publiUrl">URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="publiUrl" placeholder="Ej.: www.google.com.uy" class="form-control">
        <label for="publiText">Texto</label>
        <input type="text" name="texto" id="publiText" placeholder="Ej.: Google" class="form-control">
        <label for="publiImg">Imagen</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="publiImagen">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-form-pub" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form-pub" id="btn-add-pub">Guardar cambios</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I try to submit via ajax in the console I have the next error:

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

I has maked this anothers times but now don't work. 
Please somebody can help? Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390598/append-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-formdata)

Comment: May not solve your problem. But may I suggest using [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute instead

Comment: thanks you for the required attribute! and Evan y saw these possible duplicate, but I had set contentType and processData to false...

Answer (score 0):

I really solved the problem, I copy and paste the code from another similar implementation and change the name variable of FormData to data

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'publicidad.ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, 
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',                  
        success: function(data) { 
            // response
        }
});
```

Comment: I really can't note the diference...??

Comment: I used method to set POST instead type... sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `processData` in the original Ajax call (as `pocessData`). That could be why it started to work when you copy-pasted from another source without making any substantial changes.